# v.dissolve renames the attribute table column and does not produce a dbf

Tags: grass-gis, vector, attribute-table, dbf

When I run v.dissolve on my vector...

```
v.dissolve --o input=pass2@mapset1 layer=1 column=fttcp output=pass3
```

The dissolving appears to work but the column name in the attribute table has changed from 'fttcp' to 'cat'.

Also, although the input has a dbf file, the output does not (so I assume it is storing the attribute table in a different format or something?).

Is there a way to tell v.dissolve to retain the original column name or is there a way to rename it?

Also, is there a reason v.dissolve doesnt write a dbf. Is there a way to get it to write the attribute table to a dbf or is there a way to convert the vector so it uses a dbf?

I am using GRASS 6.4.2 on windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is here...

http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/v-dissolve-renames-the-attribute-column-td4977208.html